# How can I delay focusing using AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, rsbarcodes

I am working on application (using Swift) which has the function to scan barcodes. For this I am using [RSBarcodes](https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift/tree/Swift1.2).

Issue I am dealing with is that I need to scan barcodes from A4 paper sheet which is full of them. However the capturing is too fast and before I can focus on the right barcode the app captures wrong one.

So basically I need to ensure that the device will not capture some barcode, I don't want, but the one I will be pointing on for a longer time. My only idea is to check if the same barcode was captured for example 10 times and based on this assume that this one is the right one. Is there some more elegant solution?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iOS dev, so I don't know the specifics - but is there a way you activate the *camera* but not the scanner? If so, if you can overlay a button in the camera view which says "Scan" - then your user would provide the trigger to capture the barcode once they have settled on a specific one.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It seems I will have to do some walk around like this.. which I don't prefer, but as a temporary solution, it should be fine.